# Spark-submit -class command not found?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running a project with kafka and Apache spark.  To run my kafka stream I am running this command from within the project:

```
$SPARK_HOME/spark-submit --class "TwitterStream" --master local[*] target/scala-2.11/scalakafka_2.11-0.1.jar
```

However I simply get the below error:

```
bash: /spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

If I add \ to the end of the command it seems to enter spark-submit, but nothing happens!

Comment: You have no SPARK_HOME variable set

Answer (score 0):

First you check you have configured SPARK_HOME properly using `echo $SPARK_HOME`. if not then run `export SPARK_HOME=<your spark folder's path>`.